# Algorithm: Overlapping 1D segments with associative key

Tags: algorithm

Given an input of logical times and a unique key for each time, how do I give back a total sequence of logical times (which may be broken up) identifying each key 'present' for that time?

For example with logical times as simple integers (that can be incremented or decremented), and keys which can compared:

```
type LogicalTime = Int
type Key = Char

-- Not necessarily ordered
skipList :: [(LogicalTime, LogicalTime, Key)]
skipList = 
    [ (100, 200, 'A')
    , (201, 300, 'B')
    , ( 20, 400, 'C')
    , (125, 150, 'D')
    , (151, 250, 'E')
    ]

expected :: [(LogicalTime, LogicalTime, [Key])]
expected =
    [ ( 20,  99, ['C'])
    , (100, 124, ['A','C'])
    , (125, 150, ['A','C','D'])
    , (151, 200, ['A','C','E'])
    , (201, 250, ['B','C','E'])
    , (251, 300, ['B','C'])
    , (301, 400, ['C'])
    ]
```

One may naively iterate over the entire range found and loop through every key entry to calculate this, though I'm looking for a more efficient approach.
(This is not language specific)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each interval `(start, end, key)` triggers two events: `add(key,start)` and `remove(key,end)`. Generate these events while iterating over the list of intervals, then sort the events by their time (`start` or `end`). Then you can go through the sorted events, generate an interval ending before the events with active keys and update the counts of keys for the next interval.

Here is some python code:

```
events = []
for start,end,key in skipList:
  events.extend([(start-1, 1, key), (end, -1, key)])
events.sort()

startTime,_,firstKey = events.pop(0)
activeKeys = {firstKey:1}
expected = []
for time,delta,key in events:
  currentKeys = [k for k in activeKeys if activeKeys[k] > 0]
  currentKeys.sort()
  if startTime < time:
    expected.append((startTime+1, time, currentKeys))
  if not key in activeKeys:
    activeKeys[key] = 0
  activeKeys[key] += delta
  startTime = time
```

For your example `skipList` the output as `expected` is generated.

Comment: This implementation is correct as far as the input and expected output.
An alternate functional version is https://gist.github.com/LeviSchuck/c34c58c295806bc23fffe82ee19e52b5

Although interestingly, it does not handle zero-width segments.

Comment: @LeviSchuck I have *simplified* the code so that it now also works for "zero-width segments"! :-) key idea: the time of an event now always specifies the point, after which a key is added or removed.